# SharePoint 2010: MySite title holding old information

Tags: my-site, mysites

On SharePoint 2010 with MySite configured, I have the title field to be exported to AD after being changed.

I have one particular issue whereby AD holds the correct information, and when I edit the user's mysite profile through Central Admin it holds the right info also.

However, when I do a people search in the prod environment, I see that it displays his old title.

has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Has a full crawl been triggered since the change?

Comment: I would think so, the entry should have been made days ago and I have a full crawl run nightly at 2am

Comment: When is the last time that the User Profile Synchronization job has been performed? When is the last time that the Search Service Application has crawled ?

Comment: I can see errors in the ULS logs.

06/12/2013 16:26:00.42  mssdmn.exe (0x1CFC)                      0x27AC SharePoint Server Search       PHSts                          dv3p High     CSTS3Accessor::GetServer fails, Url sts4://mysite.domain.local/siteurl=personal/smithcr/siteid={bc790093-91fd-4501-992d-9e645041945c}, hr=80041205  [sts3acc.cxx:185]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3acc.cxx

When I try and browse to that address, I get prompted to login.